# Align material icon vertically

Tags: css

I am trying to vertically align my "dropdown arrow" in a naviation menu.

I have tried varioust hings like vertical-align: middle, display: inline-block and stuff like that but that didn't help at all.
http://img02.imgland.net/jfCmDoW.png

**The HTML looks like this:**

```
  <li>
    <a href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">English
      <i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>
    </a>
  </li>
```

I have created a JSFiddle which demonstrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/dbwaoLrh/

Explanations of what I am doing wrong there are highly appreciated as I face this issue every time I am using "custom" font sizes using the materialize-framework.

Comment: Use flexbox if you don't need to support IE8

Comment: The "i" tag is for italic text. For icons, use "span" or "div". In this case, you probably want "span".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You might have tried various `styling` to arrange your `icons`, but you need to target your `icons i.e. i tag` as below and style,

```
.footer-links > li > a > i{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Check this `two jsFiddle`, I have added `background` to one just for understanding purpose.

https://jsfiddle.net/dbwaoLrh/2/

https://jsfiddle.net/dbwaoLrh/4/

Comment: I have checked it, but it is still not aligned in the middle: http://img02.imgland.net/ZdETceM.png

Comment: @kentor Just add margin-top:-1px, to make it more in center. But the correct way would be vertical-align.

Comment: I used vertical-align: bottom now, that seems to be better for some reason. I think your suggestion is the best way, hence I have accepted it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

```
.material-icons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Initially skipped this answer, as it had no upvotes. And then it turns out that this is the only answer that works. Kudos!

Comment: If you are positioning it alongside text, you can also put that CSS on the parent container

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
.material-icons {
    vertical-align: 1px; /*Change this to adjust the icon*/
}
```

Second option is you can use is:

```
.material-icons {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px; /*Change this to adjust the icon*/
}
```

**What you are doing wrong**

There is css rule for icon: **font-size:24px** which is greater than the parent anchor element and line height is 1 so resulting line height is 24px; that's why it was not working. If you want you can use your own code just **change the line-height equal to parent anchor element** and use **vertical-align:middle** for icon

See [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbwaoLrh/5/)

Answer (score 13):

You should add `vertical-align: middle;` rule for `.material-icons`:-

```css
.material-icons {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know it is an old question, but i find this solutions working better with every line-height:

```
        .material-icons {
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 1px;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I was using font Awesome and to get the exact same Vertical Align with Material Font, I setup this CSS and it aligns perfectly

```
.material-icons {
vertical-align: middle;
padding-bottom: 3px }
```

Tested in Firefox, Chrome, InternetExplorer and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

MUI Icons don't inherit font size by default. It's mis-aligned because of that.

If using React, you can add `fontSize="inherit"`.

In the fiddle in this example you can add `.material-icons.material-icons { font-size: 13px; }` to fix the alignment, though it's obviously not a very pretty fix.

If you do want a bigger icon then the other answers explain how that can be aligned, but ultimately the cause of the mis-alignment is the font size difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing issues with the previous solutions, you can try this CSS code, and make sure to add it to your material icon tag. In this example, the icon tag looks like this:

```
<i class="material-symbols-rounded">calendar_month</i>
```

Here's the CSS code to be added:

```
.material-symbols-rounded {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```