# In Material UI how can I modify MuiBotton-endIcon's margin left?

Tags: material-ui

New to Material UI I'm building a navigation component while reading through the docs and I ran across [Buttons with icons and label](http://Buttons%20with%20icons%20and%20label). Wanting to build a button I created my component but there is a large gap between the text and icon.

Button:

```js
<Button
onClick={selected}
{...{
  size: 'small',
  'aria-label': 'menu',
  'aria-haspopup': 'true',
}}
className={navBtn}
endIcon={<MenuIcon />}
>
Menu
</Button>
```

When I review button in the browser the rendered element is:

```html
<span class="MuiButton-endIcon">
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
<path d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z"></path>
</svg>
</span>
```

followed with the CSS of:

```css
.MuiButton-endIcon {
    display: inherit;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Wanting to modify the CSS of the margin left I attempted to target `MuiButton-endIcon`:

```css
navBtn: {
  color: '#363537',
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    boxShadow: 'none',
  },
  '&:focus': {
    boxShadow: 'none',
  },
  MuiButtonEndIcon: {
    marginLeft: '2px',
  },
},
```

which did not work. The only hack I can get to work is to add a `span` with inline styling:

```js
<Button
onClick={selected}
{...{
  size: 'small',
  'aria-label': 'menu',
  'aria-haspopup': 'true',
}}
className={navBtn}
endIcon={<MenuIcon />}
>
<span style={{ marginRight: '-6px' }}>Menu</span>
</Button>
```

the full component:

```js
import React from 'react'

// Material UI
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu'

// Styles
import useStyles from '../styles'

const NavIcon = ({ selected }) => {
  const { navBtn } = useStyles()

  return (
    <Button
      onClick={selected}
      {...{
        size: 'small',
        'aria-label': 'menu',
        'aria-haspopup': 'true',
      }}
      className={navBtn}
      endIcon={<MenuIcon />}
    >
      <span style={{ marginRight: '-6px' }}>Menu</span>
    </Button>
  )
}

export default NavIcon
```

Research:

- [Align material icon vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360526/align-material-icon-vertically)
- [How to Align tab-label and tab-icon horizontally in material-UI using Tabs API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289639/how-to-align-tab-label-and-tab-icon-horizontally-in-material-ui-using-tabs-api)
- [Centered icon and text (React Material-UI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62857325/centered-icon-and-text-react-material-ui)
- [Material UI - Align icon to center with the Typography text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179266/material-ui-align-icon-to-center-with-the-typography-text)

In Material UI is there a way to modify the margin from the `<MenuIcon />` to the text with a `<Button />` without implementing an inline style hack on the text?

---

### Edit

Per the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65740907/1952287) that mentioned [spacing](https://material-ui.com/system/spacing/) I tried the following:

on `<Button>`:

```js
<Button
m={1}
onClick={selected}
{...{
  size: 'small',
  'aria-label': 'menu',
  'aria-haspopup': 'true',
}}
className={navBtn}
endIcon={<MenuIcon />}
>
Menu
</Button>
```

on `<MenuIcon>`:

```js
<Button
onClick={selected}
{...{
  size: 'small',
  'aria-label': 'menu',
  'aria-haspopup': 'true',
}}
className={navBtn}
endIcon={<MenuIcon m={1} />}
>
Menu
</Button>
```

styling:

```css
navBtn: {
  color: '#363537',
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    boxShadow: 'none',
  },
  '&:focus': {
    boxShadow: 'none',
  },
},
```

and there is no effect on the margin to the component. My understanding from the docs for spacing to work I would need to build a theme.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65725395/11247175) will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for every component of the material-ui, they take a `classes` prop, by which you can target the inside classes directly. For `endIcon`, button receives a style object to `endIcon` key in `classes` prop.

#### App.js

```
import React from 'react'

// Material UI
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu'

// Styles from style.js
import styles from './styles'


const NavIcon = ({ selected }) => {
  const classes = styles()

  return (
    <Button
      {...{
        size: 'small',
        'aria-label': 'menu',
        'aria-haspopup': 'true',
      }}
      classes={{endIcon:classes.endIcon}}
      endIcon={<MenuIcon />}
      className={classes.navBtn}
    >
      <span style={{ marginRight: '-6px' }}>Menu</span>
    </Button>
  )
}

export default NavIcon
```

#### styles.js

```
import { makeStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    endIcon:{
      marginLeft:'4px'
    },
    navBtn: {
      color: '#363537',
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        boxShadow: 'none',
      },
      '&:focus': {
        boxShadow: 'none',
      },
    },
  }),
);

export default useStyles
```

Add the required margin in `endIcon` class.

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

[Documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/button/)

Comment: Interesting approach but how can someone incorporate `navBtn` CSS from `makeStyles` with `createStyles` in one so it can be moved to a document like *styles.js*? I see that `navBtn` is changed from `className` to `classes`.

Comment: create another class in styles.js object for the end icon and then pass that class to the endIcon

Comment: ya I see that but what I'm wondering is if I have two style objects from a file what is the best way to bring each on it and use two different styles from two different objects.

Comment: now check the answer. Are you talking about something like this??

Comment: can also be done in one prop: `classes={{ root: classes.navBtn, endIcon: classes.endIcon }}`

Answer (score 0):

From the [Spacing](https://material-ui.com/system/spacing/) docs

In order for it to work you have to wrap the element you want in a so called "Box"

```
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
```

You can specify a prop called "m" to the Button, for example:

```
<Box m="5px"> <Button /> </Box>
```

This adds 5 pixels to the overall margin of the button, but if you want to apply only margin to the left you can do:

```
<Box ml="5px"> <Button /> </Box>
```

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work when applied to the `<Button>` or `<MenuIcon>`. Edited into question.

Comment: I edited my response! you have to wrap it on a component called "Box" for it to work.

Comment: That doesn't work because it targets the whole button when the text `Menu` is the child of `<Button>`. When you apply the `<Box>` and margin this moved the entire button component when the question states that I'm targeting the component margin with the text.